# Change the value of ng-model field based upon a conditional ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, enums

I hope you guys can help me.

**I want to set the value of one of my AngularJS view fields based upon a (seemingly) simple conditional statement.**

And I do believe the answer is going to be so simple, yet I haven't been able to find it after more than an hour of searching and trying stuff.

I think I might be trying to use the wrong directive (I have tried stuff like ng-if and ng-change).

**This is what I want to achieve:**

When I change the report Frequency to be Weekly `(ng-if="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyId == Enum.ReportFrequency.Weekly)` set the value of my ng-model field `reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyWeekdayName = "None"`.

And visa-versa; When I change the report Frequency to be Monthly `(ng-if="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyId != Enum.ReportFrequency.Weekly)` set the value of my ng-model field `reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyMonthDayName = "None"`.

```
<!-- Frequency -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Frequency</label>
    <div class="input-dropdown">
        <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Report Frequency"
                        ng-model="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName"
                        ng-options="reportSettingsData.SelectableReportFrequencyNames"
                        cc-fields="ReportFrequencyName"
                        ng-change="frequencyChanged()"
                        cc-key-field="ReportFrequencyId"
                        cc-allow-search="reportSettingsData.SelectableReportFrequencyNames != null && reportSettingsData.SelectableReportFrequencyNames.length > 5"
                        name="iFrequencyName">
        </cc-dropdown>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Week Days / Month Days -->
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Frequency Options</label>
    <div class="input-dropdown" ng-if="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyId != Enum.ReportFrequency.Weekly">
        <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Report Frequency Option"
                        ng-model="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyMonthDayName"
                        ng-options="reportSettingsData.SelectableReportFrequencyMonthDays"
                        ng-disabled="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyId != Enum.ReportFrequency.Monthly"
                        cc-fields="ReportFrequencyMonthDayName"
                        cc-key-field="ReportFrequencyMonthDayId"
                        cc-allow-search="true"
                        name="iFrequencyMonthDays">
        </cc-dropdown>
    </div>

    <div class="input-dropdown" ng-if="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyId == Enum.ReportFrequency.Weekly">
        <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Report Frequency Option"
                        ng-model="reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyWeekdayName"
                        ng-options="reportSettingsData.SelectableReportFrequencyWeekdays"
                        cc-fields="ReportFrequencyWeekdayName"
                        cc-key-field="ReportFrequencyWeekdayId"
                        cc-allow-search="true"
                        name="iFrequencyWeekdays">
        </cc-dropdown>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thank you greatly in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ng-if directive is used to remove or create a dom element based on condition, refer this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf.

For your use case it is not required.

Bind to ng-change event and in the function set appropriate value on the model field.

```
$scope.frequencyChanged = function(){
   if($scope.reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyName.ReportFrequencyId == Enum.ReportFrequency.Weekly){
   $scope.reportSettingsData.ReportFrequencyWeekdayName = "None".
  }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion, and it works for the intended purpose, but not as I expected. If you are willing, please see my edited question. Thanks!